# Do I need to close fds when reading and writing to the pipe among threads created using pthread_create?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, unix, pipe

There is a client server application I am working on. Below is the code from client side.

`pipe_input`, `pipe_output` are shared variables.

```
        int fds[2];
            if (pipe(fds)) {
                        printf("pipe creation failed");
                    }  else {
                        pipe_input = fds[0];
                        pipe_output = fds[1];
                        reader_thread_created = true;
                        r = pthread_create(&reader_thread_id,0,reader_thread,this);
                        }


 void* reader_thread(void *input)
    {
    unsigned char id;
        int n;
        while (1) {

            n = read(pipe_input , &id, 1);
            if (1 == n) {
                //process
            }if ((n < 0) ) {
                printf("ERROR: read from pipe failed");
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("reader thread stop");
        return 0;
    }
```

There is a writer thread also which writes data on event change from server.

```
void notify_client_on_event_change(char id)
{
    int n;
    n= write(pipe_output, &id, 1);
    printf("message written to pipe done ");
}
```

My question is do I need to close the write end in reader thread and read end in case of writer thread. In the destructor, I am waiting for reader thread to exit but sometimes it doesn't exit from reader thread.

Comment: Please be nice, and properly indent your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] do i need to close the write end in reader thread and read end in case of writer thread[?]

As those fds "*are shared*", closing them in one thread would close them for all threads. That is not what you want, I suspect.

Comment: thanks alk for replying. can you tell me that if read is blocked on an fd and i made the fd =-1 from other thread at the same time, will read return with -1 or be blocked forever.

Comment: @Euler: No, it won't, as on the call to `read()`, `read()` received a copy of the fd's value. C is pass by value. Also this is a different question, and you might like to pose it as such.